# Magento 1.9.x Payment Extension

Tags: php, magento, model-view-controller, payment-gateway, magento-1.9

I'm new to Magento 1.9.x and i need write payment extension
Now i have some troubles
i need to add fields to my data form which i must send to payment gateway,
but when i write this in my file
`\app\code\community\Ecc\Paygate\Model\Request.php`

```
class Ecc_Paygate_Model_Request extends Varien_Object

{

    const FIELD_NAME_MERCHANT_ID = 'MerchantID';
    const FIELD_NAME_MERCHANT_SECRET_KEY = 'TerminalID';
    const FIELD_NAME_PAYMENT_TIME = '';
    const FIELD_NAME_PAYMENT_NO = 'OrderID';
    const FIELD_NAME_PAYMENT_CURRENCY = '980';
    const FIELD_NAME_PAYMENT_AMOUNT = 'TotalAmount';
    const FIELD_NAME_SESSION = 'aa';
    const FIELD_NAME_PAYMENT_DESC = 'PurchaseDesc';
```

i get error in app\code\community\Ecc\Paygate\controllers\PaymentController.php   on this line

> Fatal error: Call to a member function toHtml() on boolean in /app/code/community/Ecc/Paygate/controllers/PaymentController.php on line 28

```
$this->getResponse()->setBody($block->toHtml());

class Ecc_Paygate_PaymentController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{

    public function redirectAction()
    {
        $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('ecc_paygate/method_form', 'paygate_redirect',
            array('template' => 'paygate/redirect.phtml'));
        $this->getResponse()->setBody($block->toHtml());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

method createBlock returns false in case if given block class does not exist

```
public function createBlock($type, $name='', array $attributes = array())
{
    try {
        $block = $this->_getBlockInstance($type, $attributes);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        Mage::logException($e);
        return false;
    }
```

so 'ecc_paygate/method_form' seems invalid.

Isn’t a paygate extension already available? [here](https://developer.paygate.co.za/product/62)